# Front end validation for rails select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, select

**Select Field:**

```
<%= f.select :study_material_type, StudyMaterial::TYPES.map{|v| [v,v]}, selected: f.object.try(:study_material_type) , required: true,include_blank: "Please select a Study Material"%>
```

I want to validate the presence of `:study_material_type`  select field. How can I do this?

Comment: What are you trying to validate here?

Answer (score -1):

Select takes in 5+ options while `required` validation is a `html_option`
 i.e

```
select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

put the html arguments in `{ }` as a `html_options`. This should work for you.

```
<%= f.select :study_material_type, StudyMaterial::TYPES.map{|v| [v,v]}, {include_blank: "Please select a Study Material"}, {required: true } %>
```

[Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select) is a good material for you to understand better.

Comment: `undefined local variable or method `required' for #<#<Class:0x0000000a35de78>:0x0000000aea60a0>`

Comment: @sree Edited. Try that again

Comment: I just edit the answer and I have working on my machine 

`<%= f.select :study_material_type, StudyMaterial::TYPES.map{|v| [v,v]}, {include_blank: "Please select a Study Material"}, {required: true } %>`

this should work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97867/discussion-between-callmesurge-and-sree).